# org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for... media type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs, wildfly

I've written a series of JAX-RS services that are deployed in a WAR file on Wildfly 11.  I have the `@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })` annotation on them, indicating that I want to receive JSON or XML as the response from the service.  I have a series of data transfer objects annotated with JAXB annotations.  These are the objects that will be returned by my service.  I've tested using JSON and everything works as expected.  However, when I went to test using an `"Accept: application/xml"` header so I could get back XML, I got the following Exception in my logs:

> org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not
>   find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.test.MyObject
>   of media type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8

I'm not sure where the `;charset=UTF-8` came from.  I'm not specifying that in my `Accept` header.  I also don't see `;charset=UTF-8` anywhere when I using `application/json` as my `Accept` type.  Additionally, I'm logging all of my request headers, and don't see `;charset=UTF-8` appearing anywhere, so it's definitely not something being added from my side.

Has anyone encountered this before?  I know I haven't, so I am at a loss as to why this is happening.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a default constructor in the model class? And don't worry about the charset. It has nothing to do with a provider not being found. If you do have the default constructor, then can you post the model class so we can test it out.

Comment: Can you show example of the sent XML against `MyObject` properties?

Comment: @PaulSamsothayes, I have a default constructor

Comment: @user7294900 I am performing a POST and expecting application/xml to be returned when I get the Exception.

Comment: Can you example of xml you are sending?maybe it's invalid

Comment: This string most probably comes from "Content-type" header of response. Do you log response headers?

Comment: Please add the full stack-trace. Did you also add  resteasy-jaxb-provider for marshaling xml to java objects?

Comment: did you try connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml"); or connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8"); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your data transfer object (eg com.test.MyObject) is annotated with @XmlRootElement and not @XmlElement. If not, this might be the cause...

Comment: I was missing @XmlRootElement on one of my objects.  For JSON it wasn't required, but for XML that was the cause of the issue.